# Step by step process / How to Read Azure app Configurations keys in Data bricks Notebooks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-app-configuration

In Azure Data bricks notebook, I Have a scenario to filter records/result set based on list of values. This filter may change in the future. Since it can change in the future, I want to configure this list, so that it can be changed with support help in the future without notebooks deployment.

As we are not using Azure SQL in our implementation /design to configure these values, thinking to use App Configuration. I understand that Azure App Configuration is something related web application.

But since, Azure App Configuration is a cloud component, is it possible to read the azure App Configuration keys in Azure Data bricks notebooks.

If yes, please share the step-by-step process for authentication and the code (Py spark) to read the keys.

If this is not possible, what is an alternative way to achieve this scenario in Azure data bricks notebook?

I dint try anything. looking for an approach.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Azure Databricks in a while but since the notebooks support Python, you should be able to do the following

- Use the [Azure App Configuration Python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-python?tabs=windowscommandprompt). You can install libraries from pypi as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/notebooks-python-libraries).
- You can use the Connection String as shown in the previous doc or leverage an [Azure Service Principal](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/appconfiguration/azure-appconfiguration#use-aad-token) if you prefer
- While I don't have sample notebook to share, you should be able to use more or less the same code from [the official samples for the App Configuration SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/appconfiguration/azure-appconfiguration/samples/hello_world_sample.py)